# Can I save data to the internal storage on Android in a way that the user cannot delete it?

Tags: android, file-io, storage, sharedpreferences

My understanding is that if I save any data to the internal storage of the Android platform, those can easily be deleted by the user by going to: Settings -> Applications -> Manage applications -> (choose your app) -> Clear data

Is there a way to save data (or SharedPreferences) in a way that it is not deletable by the user?

Comment: you can put it in a place that is not concerned by the clear data option, but I don't know if this can be on the internal storage

Comment: I am sorry could you clarify what you mean by 'can put it in a place that is not concerned by the clear data option'?

Comment: basically any directory outside your package data directory. if you create a file in, say, /sdcard/something, it will not be deleted if your user clears the data (at least i don't think it will)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two sides to what you are asking.

First, is there a way to store data that a user cannot delete.

NO, that is not possible, nor should it be.

Second, is there a way to store data outside of the area that is erased when 'clear data' is called while managing an application.

Yes, that is possible. You need to add permission to access the SD-card see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html), and [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html). Look for

```
WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

For full details on accessing external storage, see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal)

**EDIT:**

There is NO way to save data (SharedPreferences) in a way that is not deletable by the User, nor SHOULD there be. That would be a great way for a malicious app to do malicious things to a phone (to, if nothing else, fill up the internal storage on the phone and make it fail, with no option to 'clear data' to fix it).

To save data that is not deleted by using the Clear Data option in settings. Your only options are to save to 'external storage' which counts as both the 'internal sd-card' and the 'external sd-card'. Basically, anywhere that is NOT deletable via Clear Data.

I believe this answers your question. If it does not, then clarify what you want to know instead of saying 'it doesn't answer my question' in a comment. Tell me what I'm not answering, and PLEASE choose the most correct answer if there is one.

Comment: Well if you look at the whole question the actual answer is no based on your reply, but thanks for the answer it clears it up :-)

Answer (score 0):

If data is not huge, write it to an xml file in your project. There is no way to delete it without uninstalling the application.

Comment: How can I write it to an xml file? I am thinking of saving dynamic data which I would obtain after installing the app. e.g: user specific info

Comment: I do not mind that android allows to do that. Maybe you can use assets, but I am not sure about  this is  what you want or not.